# how we can connecte combochart with"Controls and dashboards"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i have combochart

```
!function($) { 
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function populateSelectWithOptions(target, data)
    {
        console.log(data, typeof(data));
        var $select =$("#"+target);
        $select.empty();
        for(var i=0; i <data.length;i++){
        $select.append($("<option>").attr("value", data[i]).text(data[i]));
        }

        $select.prop('disabled', false);
        $select.change(function (){
            var e = document.getElementById("groupe");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            //alert(strUser);
            sendQuery(strUser)

        });

        // baraie inke vaghti bara avalin bar safe lod mishavad dar chekbox chizi vojod dashte bashad
        $select.trigger('change');
        //console.log(populateSelectWithOptions(target, data));
        };


       function sendQuery(cityName) {
            // You can manipulate the variable response
            // Success!  
          var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://api.XXX.com/XXX/datasource?table='+cityName);
            query.setQuery("select (cost_reportings_timestamp), sum (cost_reportings_cost) group by (cost_reportings_timestamp)  pivot ecoadmin_zone_name");
            //Send the query with a callback function.
          query.send(drawChart);
        console.log(response);
        }

       function drawChart(response) {
             if (response.isError()) {
             alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
             return;
        }   
             var data = response.getDataTable();
             console.log(data);
             var options = {'title':'XXXXX ........',

                           'width':1000,
                           'height':600,
                           'seriesType': 'bars',
                           'isStacked':'True' 
                          };
             var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
             chart.draw(data, options);
             var chart2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_table'));
             chart2.draw(data, options);


             // clickabale        
       } 
        function initialize() {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','chart_div');            
            $('#reportingContainer').append($newDiv);

            $($newDiv).hide();  //hide the div here

            // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
            // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
            getTable();
        } 
             // baraie inke vaghti ro elemenha click mikonim piecharto ieshon bede
            $("#groupe").change( function () {
            $('#chart_div').toggle(); //If it is visible hide it or vice versa
              //..
        });

    function getTable() {
            $.getJSON('call/json/mytables', {}, function (response){
            console.log(response);
            populateSelectWithOptions("groupe", response);
        })
        }
    // request the data
    getTable();

}(jQuery);
```

and kow i want to controls my ComboChart with one Controls and Dashborards, this is the codes:

```
!function($) { 
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function populateSelectWithOptions(target, data)
    {
        console.log(data, typeof(data));
        var $select =$("#"+target);
        $select.empty();
        for(var i=0; i <data.length;i++){
        $select.append($("<option>").attr("value", data[i]).text(data[i]));
        }

        $select.prop('disabled', false);
        $select.change(function (){
            var e = document.getElementById("groupe");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            //alert(strUser);
            sendQuery(strUser)

        }); 
        $select.trigger('change');
        };
       function sendQuery(cityName) {

          var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://api.XXX.com/XXX/datasource?table='+cityName);

          query.setQuery("select (cost_reportings_timestamp), sum (cost_reportings_cost) group by (cost_reportings_timestamp)  pivot ecoadmin_zone_name");
            //Send the query with a callback function.
          query.send(drawChart);
        console.log(response);
        }

       function drawChart(response) {
             if (response.isError()) {
             alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
             return;
        }   
             var data = response.getDataTable();

             var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                    containerId: 'control',
                    options: {
                        // Filter by the date axis.
                        filterColumnIndex: 0,
                        ui: {
                            chartType: 'LineChart',
                            chartOptions: {
                                chartArea: {
                                    width: '90%'
                                },
                                hAxis: {
                                    baselineColor: 'none'
                                }
                            },

                            chartView: {
                                columns: [0,1]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    //Initial range: 2010 to 2021
                    state: {
                        range: {
                            start: new Date(2012),
                            end: new Date(2019)
                        }
                    }
                })

             // Define a bar chart
                var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'ComboChart',
                    containerId: 'chart1',
                    options: {
                        width: 400,
                        height: 300,
                        hAxis: {
                            minValue: 0,
                            maxValue: 60
                        },
                        chartArea: {
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            bottom: 0
                        },
                    },
                    view: {columns: [0, 1]}
                });

             // Create the dashboard.    
                var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
                // Configure the slider to affect the bar chart
                bind([control], [ComboChart]).
                // Draw the dashboard
                draw(data);

       } 
        function initialize() {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','chart_div');            
            $('#reportingContainer').append($newDiv);

            $($newDiv).hide();  //hide the div here

            // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
            // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
            getTable();
        } 
             // baraie inke vaghti ro elemenha click mikonim piecharto ieshon bede
            $("#groupe").change( function () {
            $('#chart_div').toggle(); //If it is visible hide it or vice versa
              //..
        });

    function getTable() {
            $.getJSON('call/json/mytables', {}, function (response){
            console.log(response);
            populateSelectWithOptions("groupe", response);
        })
        }
    // request the data
    getTable();

}(jQuery);
```

and this is Structure of my  " var data = response.getDataTable(); "

cost_reportings_timestamp, Bureau de M. le Maire, Salle de réunion, Secrétariat /accueil

8 déc. 2012, 0.4536628723144531, 2.1034255027770996, 1.1031612157821655

but it doesn't works????!!!!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/armon000/ZQ9w3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you're trying to use a non-existing variable. When you bind your dashboard, it says

```
bind([control], [ComboChart]).
```

but you never defined the variable ComboChart. I think what you actually meant to write was

```
bind([control], [barChart]).
```

Comment: .no, i want to use ComboChart and also i think that i defined the variable ComboChart....  "chartType: 'ComboChart',"

Comment: yes that's write but now just i can see my (var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                    containerId: 'control',) and i can't see my ( var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'ComboChart',
                    containerId: 'chart1',)        i have this error in my page (One or more participants failed to draw()) and this error in console ([15:34:41,596] Une chaîne vide a été transmise à « getElementById())